# NUnit and Postsharp aspects not working

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, postsharp

My question is quite simple. I have come to the following case:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyAspectTest
{

    [MyAspect]
    public void DummyMethod(int integerInput)
    {
          var dummyVariable = 1;
    }

    [Test]
    public void AttributeTest()
    {
        DummyMethod(0);
    }
}
```

The MyAspect:

```
public class MyAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var test = 1;
    }
}
```

When I debug AttributeTest with a breakpoint at "var test = 1;", it never breaks, which means the aspect's "OnInvoke" never runs. The dummyVariable line is ran and the test ends successfully.

Why?

Comment: Is PostSharp executed when you build the project? You should see the message from PostSharp in the build log output. And there should be an <Import ... /> line in your csproj that includes PostSharp.targets.

Comment: @AlexD, When I run my web project it works. When I run the test, it does not.

Comment: Please verify that you've installed the PostSharp NuGet package in the test project. And that PostSharp.targets is imported in csproj file.